# Javascript Regex - non-greedy "leading" matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have done extensive reading, but have trouble solving this scenario. I want to matching everything in between `abc` and `xyz`, in a non greedy way - without any extra `abc` or `xyz` in the matched string.

For example, if my input is `abc abc xyz xyz`,  i want to get `abc xyz` as the output. If I use `/abc.*?xyz/g` as the expression, it returns `abc abc xyz`. `xyz` is matched non greedily. How can I get `abc` also matched non-greedily?

For the input like, `abc pqr abc lmn xyz lmn xyz`, output should be `abc lmn xyz`

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Comment: Based on @WiktorStribiżew's hint, maybe `abc(?:(?!abc|xyz).)*?xyz`. As Wiktor notes, the tempered greedy token construct is expensive.

Comment: That is not a hint, that is the answer, see [`abc(?:(?!abc|xyz).)*xyz`](https://regex101.com/r/xU4gM0/6). You do not need to use a lazy quantifier here, since the `xyz` is an alternative in the tempering lookahead.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Following your original post, I foundthat this patterns returns what I needed. `abc(?:(?!abc).)*?xyz`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In that case, `abc(?:(?!abc).)*?xyz` would seem to perform a more efficient search.